# msgpack: Pack a tuple in Python and unpack it in Java

Tags: java, python, msgpack

I am trying to send a tuple from Python to Java using `msgpack` but I do not seem to be able of doing it

This is the code in Python

```
tuple_data = (12,  "ajonjoli", 554)
new_file = open("/tmp/tuple_ser.bin", "wb")
msgpack.pack(tuple_data, new_file)
```

Whenever I try to unpack it in Java I get an exception (`org.msgpack.core.MessageInsufficientBufferException`)

Is this possible at all?

Note: I can make it work with a dictionary in Python and a `Map` in Java

Thanks

Comment: will json do?
it can be used in multiple programming languages and easy also

Comment: JSON would definitely do it but I have only partial control on what the Python side is sending

Comment: Possible unrelated, but, are you closing the file after write (new_file.close() or using with clause) ?

Comment: can you write down the basic java code..to get an understanding of how you are doing it. Since the error is in java we need to know what went wrong there

Comment: @jgoday Not unrelated at all. That was causing it